# Pandas - skip NULL value in calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, valueerror

I need to add field to my DataFrame with calculated distance between Location A and Location B. I have this code which works fine for fields with not empty coordinates:

```
df['Distance_AB'] = df.apply(lambda x: great_circle((x['latitude_A'],x['longitude_A']), (x['latitude_B'], x['longitude_B'])).meters, axis=1).round()
```

But when it encounters empty field it throws an error:

> ValueError: ('Point coordinates must be finite. (nan, nan, 0.0) has
>   been passed as coordinates.', u'occurred at index 2881')

How can ensure that formula for great circle distance will not receive NULL value (distance calculation will be skipped when no coordinates are available)? I am aware of `pd.notnull()` function but it returns `True` or `False`.

Comment: Modify your `great_circle` function to be robust to bad inputs, OR use a [ternary conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) within your `lambda`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume either your function `great_circle` is not vectorisable or vectorisation is out of scope for your question. Since [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is already a Python-level loop, you can use an explicit function with `try` / `except` without significant additional overhead:

```
def calculator(row):
    lat_A, long_A = row['latitude_A'], row['longitude_A']
    lat_B, long_B = row['latitude_B'], row['longitude_B']
    try:
        return great_circle((lat_A, long_A), (lat_B, long_B)).meters
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan

df['Distance_AB'] = df.apply(calculator, axis=1).round()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. try/except worked fine. I only got this warning message but the output looks OK (though hard to validate due to big data size):

AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1828: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in rint result = com._values_from_object(self).round(decimals)

Comment: I have stubbornly tried to filter out NULL values inside my apply/lambda. Without much of luck. Would it be possible to achieve, what was done with try/except, with IF statement inside apply/lambda? How one can select DataFrame cell value which is not NULL? Will "if val is not None" work on DataFrame?

Comment: Perhaps your series isn't numeric: you can  try `df['Distance_AB'] = pd.to_numeric(df.apply(calculator, axis=1), errors='coerce').round()`